# Como adicionar itens num combobox dinamicamente em Java?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Tenho um projeto no netbeans que utiliza Java Swing para a interface. Tenho alguns dados no MYSQL que gostaria de mostrá-los assim que a janela for criada.

Enfim, como posso colocar itens num JComboBox de maneira dinâmica em java?

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCdgl1dlfmY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCdgl1dlfmY) Verifica essa video aula que vai te ajudar, Neste video você vai aprender a conectar com o banco, criar o crud e popular no JCombobox, e não somente jcombobox.addItem(). Que provável você já deva ter visto

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Answer (score 4):

Como não tem mais detalhes, vou te dar a resposta mais genérica possível.

É só usar o método `addItem`

```
combobox.addItem("Item 1");
combobox.addItem("Item 2");
combobox.addItem("Item 3");
```

Answer (score -1):

1) primeiro você tem fazer a conexão isso pode ser feito em JDBC Puro ou JPA

[Conexão JDBC](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-uma-conexao-java-mysql-server/16753)

[Conexão JPA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0mK1clZyGM)

2) Você cria um DAO com base em um dos exemplo

[CRUD JDBC](http://www.brunorota.com.br/2012/05/19/tutorial-criar-crud-em-java-com-jdbc-parte-1-final/)

[CRUD JPA](http://www.universidadejava.com.br/materiais/jpa-exemplo-crud/)

3) Na Sua classe JFrame você vai fazer o seguinte

```
public class SeuFrame(){

    public SeuFrame(){
        carregarCombo();
    }

    public void carregarCombo(){

          SeuDAO dao = new SeuDAO();
          List<SuaClasse> list = dao.lista();

          for(SuaClasse item: list){
               seuCombobox.addItem(item);
          }

    }        

}
```

Comment: Sinceramente sua resposta continua baseada em links. Esse código não responde a pergunta, alem de você adicionar coisas que não foram solicitadas.

Comment: Desculpem ai, humildade.
Estou chegando agora e ainda estou pegando o jeito

Comment: @DemysCota é tranquilo e ninguem esta dando bronca, isto são só orientações, então por favor leia o Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answering e seja bem vindo! ;D